# Can video data can be transmitted via radio frequency?

Tags: frequency, radio-frequency

My friend says that it's possible to transmit an video by converting it's data to radio frequency?

Comment: Sorry,  isn't this how broadcast TV works?

Comment: @M. Enns - radio wave "broadcast TV"? What's that, old-timer ?   :-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_station

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation#Digital_modulation_methods

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is indeed possible. The most common application of this would be [television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television).